# vagrant up not working ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, digital-ocean, vagrant-provision

When I run `vagrant up`  command on digitalocean server(ubuntu) it shows me the below error. This command is working fine at locally but not working at server.

```
$ vagrant up


There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["modifyvm", "d2015e22-d634-46d6-9de5-9ca5e9ecea38", "--natpf1", "delete", "ssh", "--natpf1", "delete", "tcp9100", "--natpf1", "delete", "tcp9101", "--natpf1", "delete", "tcp9102", "--natpf1", "delete", "tcp9103", "--natpf1", "delete", "tcp9104", "--natpf1", "delete", "tcp9105"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The machine 'LaunchKit_default_1473257270586_51004' is already locked for a session (or being unlocked)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)" at line 493 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox thinks your VM is still running.

1. It might be hold by a process
   run `ps -ef | grep -i "vbox"` and kill the process associated to your VM (is any)
2. If you dont find the process, force VBox to stop the VM

   ```
   VBoxManage controlvm LaunchKit_default_1473257270586_51004 poweroff
   ```